# App gets hang when opened from app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app live on appstore. When I install the app in any device & open it by tapping on `appIcon`. It works perfectly, But when i open the app from appStore by tapping on `Open` button. App is launched but gets stuck on launch screen.

Launch screen does not go away & because of that I am unable to use the app. The issue is same in iOS-10 and iOS-11.

Answer (score 0):

Here are possible solutions you can try out to resolve your issue :

> - First try to test your app in debug environment by adding exception break points & see if it generates any exception or not
> - Second thing is use crashlytics tool in your app so if any such issue occur when your app crashes or stuck due to exception than it
>     will automatically submit report to you. Its very effective tool.

Enable exception break points like this :

[image]

**Edit:**

> - If you still unable to get resolve the issue by above solutions than do 1 thing. From didFinishLunaching method comment all SDK
>     initialisations or any thing that you think could causing the issue
> - Now make a distribution build & upload to app store & do beta testing test flight
> - Once its make sure it works fine than you should uncomment 1 by 1 statements & get reach to the statement that causing the issue

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried both of your solutions but still getting the same result.

Comment: on which device you are checking ? is it iPhoneX ?

Comment: No, iPhone 6 & 7